# Classes design with virtual methods

Tags: c++, oop

How would someone solve such a problem with classes and type as least as possible code? 
Here is what I have

Base interface for everything

```
    class IWindow
    {
    public: 
        virtual void Refresh() = 0;
// another 100 virtual methods
// ...
    };
```

This interface is used inside a library that has no idea about the concrete implementation.

Here is a version of the concrete implementation

```
    class ConcreteWindow : public IWindow
    {
    public:
        void Refresh() override {}
/// the other 100 overridden methods 
    };
```

Now we have another interface that adds some additional methods and also used inside that library.

```
class IDBDetail : public IWindow
{
public:
    virtual void DoDetail() = 0;

};
```

and here is the main problem, when we create the concrete inmplementation for it

```
class IGDBDetailWrapper : public IDBDetail, public ConcreteWindow
{
public :
    void DoDetail() {}
};
```

of course the concrete class `IGDBDetailWrapper` is abstract as well because it doesn't implement those 100 methods, but I don't wanna do that, I'd like just to reuse the implementation from `ConcreteWindow`, they are all working with the same window handle but this won't compile of course.

I can copy/paste those 100 methods from `ConcreteWindow` into `IGDBDetailWrapper`, but that's an overkill, cause I might have another 10 such new interfaces and concrete implementations.

What other pattern can I use here that would help solve the question and not re-implement those 100 methods again and again?

Thx

Comment: You are just doing it wrong.  A pure interface gets pretty tedious when it has more than a handful of functions.  But worse, much worse, it gets very hard to debug.  Just don't, a "window" needs a base class to be practical.  Be sure to look how other people did this, lots and lots of GUI wrapper libraries around.

Comment: Why  not just inherit from ConcreteWindow?

Comment: It's just bad library design, because 100 methods in a base class is horrible and the inheritance relationship between `IDBDetail` and `IWindow` looks wrong. You won't find a clean solution; any client of this library will have to use one workaround or the other.

Comment: P.S.: Chances are that this library results from an attempt to translate a class hierarchy directly from some Java code base. But in Java, interface inheritance is implicitly `virtual`. IOW, `interface Base { void f(); } interface D1 extends Base {} interface D2 extends Base {} class D implements D1, D2 { @Override public void f() {}}` will work, but a C++ equivalent must explicitly specify the `virtual` keyword in the class definitions of `D1` and `D2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use virtual inheritance. If we ignore fact should `IDBDetail` inherit from `IWindow` or not, we could use virtual inheritance to solve problem with current architecture:

```
    class IWindow
    {
    public: 
        virtual void Refresh() = 0;
// another 100 virtual methods
// ...
    };

    class ConcreteWindow : virtual public IWindow
    {
    public:
        void Refresh() override {}
/// the other 100 overridden methods 
    };

class IDBDetail : virtual public IWindow
{
public:
    virtual void DoDetail() = 0;

};

class IGDBDetailWrapper : public IDBDetail, public ConcreteWindow
{
public :
    void DoDetail() {}
};
```

Now compiler will use implementation for your 101 abstract method from `ConcreteWindow`

Answer (score 3):

Your design is running into [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#TheDiamondProblem).

> Now we have another interface that adds some additional methods and
>   also used inside that library.

```
 class IDBDetail : public IWindow { 
  public:
     virtual void DoDetail() = 0;

};
```

From the description of your IDBDetail interface looks like IDBDetail should not inherit from IWindow. If its just about adding additional functionality then IDBDetail need not be a IWindow. It just needs to understand the IWindow. For example in order to make a monkey do a special things, a trainer need not be a monkey.

[Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: It won't work, cause inside that library a method uses a pointer to IDBDetail, to access methods from IWindow. I don't have a way to change that library unfortunately.

Comment: @Eugen Ok. But you still can't go with the current inheritance model if you do one of the alternatives in your question. Because diamond problem

Answer (score 3):

First, if you are using Visual Studio there are refactoring tools that can help you with that automating what could be otherwise a tedious task, second:

To me is much pointless doing the same:

```
class IDBDetail : public IWindow
{
public:
    virtual void DoDetail() = 0;

};
```

I would do that instead

```
class IDBDetail
{
public:
    virtual void DoDetail() = 0;

};
```

Interfaces should be used to abstract away responsibilities, so cluttering a Interface with already hundreds of methods with additional methods is a symptom of bad design.

However you could leverage composition one time for all, so you create **one** time a class that resolve the problem for your, and you can later **reuse** that

```
class IDBDetailWithConcreteWindow: public IDBDetail{

    IWindow * concreteWindow;
public:
    IDBDetailWithConcreteWindow(IWindow * window){
        concreteWindow = window;
    }

    void Refresh() override{
        concreteWindow->Refresh();
    }
}
```

And finally in any derived class you have just to implement methods from IDBDetail

```
IGDBDetailWrapper: public IDBDetailWithConcreteWindow{
public:

   void DoDetail() override { }
}
```

The advantage with this solution is that if you have external constraints (like a bad designed pre-existing code base) you can still use it, while the upper solution will not work if you cannot change the IDBDetail interface.

Answer (score 3):

@bashrc is right, but it should be possible to solve the problem with virtual inheritance:

```
class ConcreteWindow : public virtual IWindow {...}

class IDBDetail : public virtual IWindow {...}
```

This Wikipedia article on [virtual inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) states the solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to override all the methods in abstract class, there is no other way. Actually you shouldn't create an abstract class of 100 methods here and that's it. Perhaps You can divide it in some smaller abstract classes? However, in this case IDBDetail should not inherit after IWindow and IGBDDetailWrapper also shouldn't inherit after IWindow - and we are here.

Comment: Maybe division into smaller classes might help. I'd have to check into this.

Answer (score 2):

It will not solve your problem, but at least you can redirect execution yourself:

```
class IGDBDetailWrapper : public IDBDetail, public ConcreteWindow
{
public:
    virtual void DoDetail() override { /*work here*/ }

    virtual void Refresh() override { ConcreteWindow::Refresh(); }
    //another 100 methods
};
```

You can make the block of such redirections as a compiler `#DEFINE` and repeat it as many times as you want.

Comment: As @DarioOO said you can use `Visual Studio refactoring tools` in order to create redirections autamatically.